# Einstein Analytics difference of date and number

Tags: einstein-analytics

I'm trying to subtract the date today and a numeric number.

The formula that I'm thinking of is `NOW() - NumberOfDays__c`.

Output should be in date format (DD/MM/YYY or MM/DD/YYYY)

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: My apologies, I missed the Einstein tag. I don't have an answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, convert the now()-Date to epoch seconds, then substract the desired number of days (multiplied by 24 * 60 * 60 = 86400). Then convert this epoch seconds value back to a date.

```
 toDate(date_to_epoch(now()) - (NumberOfDays__c * 86400))
```

Edit: forgot the 24 multiplier...